# Am I sending requests with proxies right?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Here is my code

```
    while True:
        proxies_index += 1
        try:
            session = requests.session()

            # Sending a get request to a streamer's livestream
            response = session.head(url="https://cod.live/2021/05/25/daily-twitch-livestream-pick-of-the-day/",
                                    timeout=1, proxies={"http": zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225:lum-customer-hl_7d92cb5c-zone-twitchproxies-ip-158.46.169.208:lgzehj9rl6u3})

            if response.status_code == 200:
                requests_sent += 1

                if requests_sent % 10 == 0:
                    print(requests_sent)

        except Exception:
            pass
```

Currently, I am trying to create artificial viewers for someone's twitch channel. I have been sending proxies along with the request but the viewer count does not change at all. Each proxy looks basically like this: `zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225:lum-customer-hl_7d92cb5c-zone-twitchproxies-ip-158.46.169.208:lgzehj9rl6u3`

Am I using the proxy wrong? FYI, the proxies are all from brightdata

Comment: Actually, with the above code, you are not sending a GET request. It is a HEAD request. Also using a session object not suggested to make a unique request. If it is not needed you can directly call requests.get() function

Comment: any tips for my code? @AnD

Answer (score 1):

Add  `https` key into your `proxies dict` with the same proxy address. And values in proxies dict should be strings. All according to official [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies).
That should work. Also use `get` instead of `head` and dont use `session` unless you need it.
so your proxies will looks like this:

```
proxies={
"http": 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225:lum-customer-hl_7d92cb5c-zone-twitchproxies-ip-158.46.169.208:lgzehj9rl6u3',
"https": 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225:lum-customer-hl_7d92cb5c-zone-twitchproxies-ip-158.46.169.208:lgzehj9rl6u3',
}
```

P.S. And never reveal your private credentials to public! (aka proxy login and pass in your case)